# Mocking a variable when there are two of the same type

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following class:

```
public class FinanceService {

  private BookingDao bookingMasterDao;
  private BookingDao bookingDao;

  public void createRecords(FinancialSummary financialSummary) {
    BookingEntity booking = bookingDao.loadById(1);

    //do stuff with this booking object
  }
}
```

I want to mock bookingDao, so I have the following junit test class

```
public class FinanceServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private BookingDao bookingDao;

  @InjectMocks
  private FinanceService financeService = new FinanceService();

  @Before
  public void before() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);}

  @Test
  public void testCreateRecords() {
    BookingEntity bookingEntity = new BookingEntity();
    FinancialSummary financialSummary = new FinancialSummary();
    when(bookingDao.loadById(anyInt())).thenReturn(bookingEntity);

    financeService.createRecords(financialSummary);
  }
}
```

This causes a null pointer exception because `bookingMasterDao` is mocked, but `bookingDao` is not.  If I switch these two around in FinanceService, then it works.  It seems that Mockito is mocking the first one that matches that type.

Is there a way to instruct Mockito by giving it the name of the variable that you want to mock?

Comment: replacing @InjectMocks with manual injection should bypass the issue

Comment: I agree with RC also variables have feelings too! lol

Comment: When you say manual injection, do you mean pass the mocks through as part of the constructor of FinanceService?

Comment: I've just tested your code and it worked on my side

Comment: Which version of mockito do you use?

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> Note 1: If you have properties with the same type (or same erasure), it's better to name all `@Mock` annotated fields with the matching properties, otherwise Mockito might get confused and injection won't happen.

So you have to name your mocks, see [`Mock.html#name()`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mock.html#name())

(side note: as a consequence you cannot use the same mock for both DAO).

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work.  It didn't make any difference for me.

Comment: "didn't work" is a bit broad, maybe you could provide the code you tried  (in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just declare *two* mocks, one for each target DAO field:

```
public class FinanceServiceTest {
    @Mock BookingDao bookingMasterDao;
    @Mock BookingDao bookingDao;

    ...
}
```

Comment: This does work, and is the work around that I've used.  It just seems a bit odd to declare a variable that I never use.

Comment: Yes, but surely there is a method in `FinanceService` which uses the `bookingMasterDao`. So, you can add a test to `FinanceServiceTest` that will use this second mock.